# Does Firebase Database store the latest data or all the data with timestamp?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have enabled the Firebase Persistance in my application. If I am setting a value to a child such as

```
child.setValue("XYZ");
```

I am not adding value to the parent tree. I am just updating the value of one child. So here, the value will be updated again and again by the user as he uses the application like many times a day. So, my question is, if user do not have inter-net connection for days, will this thing generate bug as Firebase is storing these things in cache. Does all the data get stored offline with mechanism something like commits in git or just the latest value is stored. I am asking this thing because it's kind of cache so if firebase stores data with all the logs and values the child gets then it can make my application buggy and slow as it will carry all the cache all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting offline and you are updating a single record than, when your getting back online, only your last update will be updated on the server. Let's take an example. You have a product in which you store a `timestamp`. Every time you make an update, you change that timestamp with the current timestamp. If you are offline and you edit that product several times, when you'll be back online, only the last timpstamp will be added on the server.

But remember, this not happening when you add new data. When you do this, all the new data is added on the server accordingly to time you have added. This happening also when you delete.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your support but it would be great if you provide some link to the information or some kind of official statements regarding it. Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look on the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

Comment: But I can not find the official sayings that firebase does not store all the values that a key has been set to or something like that.

Comment: Firebase stores all the values locally. In case of an update, as you may know, Firebase uses a `Map` to update a location. Because an update uses the same key, in stead of adding new data, your are overwriting the existing one. With other words, in the case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one. So that's the reason you'll `only` get the last update.